# What approaches are there to resolving the problem of new theories in Bayesian epistemology?

Tags: epistemology, bayesian

Bayesianism is thought to have a problem accounting for the development of new theories/beliefs. Since Bayesians would like to proceed by updating prior credences in response to new evidence via Bayesian conditionalization, the discovery/invention of new theories poses a problem: how do we determine what credence these new theories should receive, and how should our other credences be adjusted accordingly?

What is the state of work on this problem? What are the most promising candidate solutions?

Comment: See Solomonoff's algorithmic probability and the theory of universal inductive inference which combines Occam's razor, principle of multiple explanations, universal Turing machine and Bayes’ rule for prediction. All observations have the form of finite binary strings, and the universal prior is a probability distribution over the set of finite binary strings. The prior is universal in the Turing-computability sense, i.e. no string has zero probability. It is not computable, but by Levin Search it generates a sequence of approximations which converge to the universal probability distribution...

Comment: @DoubleKnot Perfect. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: In principle, the Bayesian approach does not score theories, it only assesses the plausibility of a theory given experimental data. If new experimental evidence is difficult to explain from an old theory, the probability that the old theory is updated in view of the new data, simply  this probability decreases as more experimental data becomes available. Whereas the new theory becomes more probable, given the increasing experimental evidence.